# Erase Recent Folder in Nautilus via Terminal Command

Tags: command-line, nautilus, history

Can I empty out Recent folder in Nautilus by typing terminal command, and if yes, do I have to re-log in to my system to see the effect?

Answer (score 2):

```
rm ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

and you have to logout/login